# PHP : Remote server can't handle local file

Tags: php, fopen, handle

I found myself in an issue where my PHP code works perfectly on my local computer, but not so much on my remote server. The problem is, on the remote server, the handle is NULL instead of being a ressource.

Html Form :

```
    <form action="Formulaire_admin_insertion_sauvegarder.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="formulaire" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label for="type_insertion">Type d'insertion :</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="type_insertion" value="">
                <input type="radio" name="type_insertion" value="O">O
                <input type="radio" name="type_insertion" value="N">N
            <label for="filename">CSV File:</label>
            <input type="file" multiple name="filename" id="filename"><br /><br />
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Insérer</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

PHP script that follows :

```
include('db_connect.php');
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
//Import uploaded file to Database

$type_insertion = $_POST["type_insertion"];

if (($handle = fopen($_FILES["filename"]['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE && $handle != NULL) {
    fgetcsv($handle); //skip first line
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,0, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        // SQL INSERT QUERY

    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erreur.');</script>";
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Fichier importé avec succès.');</script>";
echo "<script>document.location='Formulaire_admin.php'</script>";
```

I'm 100% sure the query works properly.

Comment: Have You tried `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see possible errors?

Comment: BTW according to documentation, `fopen()`'s result should be resource or `FALSE` - are You sure it is `NULL`?

Comment: Not sure how a shared host would configure a shared Temp file? But it might be better to move the file to somewhere you definitely have access to in the normal UPLOAD way and then read the filefrom there

Comment: @RomanHocke Yes it is null

Comment: Have You tried the error_reporting? Please try this minimalistic script: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); $handle = fopen($_FILES["filename"]['tmp_name'], "r"); var_dump($handle);`, nothing more.

Comment: @RomanHocke it returns bool(False)

Comment: Ok, then it is not `NULL` :-) Does it write some error or warning message, too?

Comment: Also, please, add `var_dump(error_get_last())`, maybe error reporting is supressed in some other way.

Comment: @RomanHocke No error message, though I solved it, the php.ini file didn't had a upload_tmp_dir location. Thanks for helping !